# How to use a name of a list in a clause?

Tags: prolog

```
taglist([classique, baroque, jazz, blues, country, rock, pop]).

distance(Tag1, Tag2, D) :-
    pos(Tag1, **taglist**, A),
    pos(Tag2, **taglist**, B),
    D is abs(A-B).
```

Comment: pos/3 is for finding the position of my tag in list for EX;  pos(jazz, taglist, D).  D = 2. OR pos(classique, taglist, D). D = 0.

Comment: and actualy i put the list like that  [classique, baroque, jazz, blues, country, rock, pop] instead of just writing his name (taglist)..and it works but it s not reasonable.

Comment: You'd do something like `taglist(L), pos(Tag1, L, A), pos(Tag2, L, B),...` Remember this is Prolog. So you're querying, `taglist(L)` asking what a valid `taglist` is and it will provide it. If there are more than one, then more will be obtained through backtracking. It instantiates `L` via `taglist` fact you asserted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think `pos/3` exist in SWI-Prolog, but `nth0/3` is similar to what you explain, except for the argument positions. The following code would do the trick:

```
taglist([classique, baroque, jazz, blues, country, rock, pop]).

distance(Tag1, Tag2, D):-
  taglist(L),
  nth0(A, L, Tag1),
  nth0(B, L, Tag2),
  D is abs(A - B).
```

Is the members of `L` are all unique you could put a cut after the second `nth0/3` to force determinism (and make the predicate semi-deterministic).